# cargar archivo xml a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, xml

Muy buenas,

Dispongo de un xml como este:

```
    <DS>
        <LAT>
            <ATE>Nacional</ATE>
        </LAT>
        <LDS>
            <DSA>
                <NIF></NIF>
                <APE></APE>
                <RC>8132404VL1083S</RC>
                <PROV></PROV>
                <MUN></MUN>
                <POL></POL>
                <PAR></PAR>
                <ERR></ERR>
                <LBI>
                    <BIE>
                        <IBI>
                            <DEL>28</DEL>
                            <MUN>90</MUN>
                            <TIP>UR</TIP>
                            <RCA>
                                <PCA>8132404VL1083S</PCA>
                                <CAR>0001</CAR>
                                <CDC1>A</CDC1>
                                <CDC2>L</CDC2>
                            </RCA>
                            <USO>Industrial</USO>
                            <SUP>30</SUP>
                        </IBI>
                        <DTR>CL REDONDILLO 8(Z) 28411 MORALZARZAL (MADRID)</DTR>
                        <DT>
                            <LOINE>
                                <CP>28</CP>
                                <CM>90</CM>
                            </LOINE>

...Contuinua con muchos registros pero con la misma estructura
```

La idea es sacar un dataframe que contenga columnas por cada etiqueta...
El caso es que he intentado su lectura para pandas sin éxito. Pues no itera sobre las etiquetas hijas, tambien he intentado con read_xml pero igualmente no he tenido exito.

Comment: ¿qué has intentado? Y ¿podrías poner también un XML completo, aunque no tenga todos los datos que al menos sea un XML válido de modo que podamos hacer alguna prueba con él? O si lo prefieres un enlace a un sitio desde donde se pueda descargar el XML

Comment: Sii imprimis lo que te devuelve el read_xml que te sale? Ademas, como tienes el código para leerlo??

Comment: Pues dejo aqui https://github.com/cafepoetica/Xml un archivo, con la lectura del pd.read_xml saca algo asi: 0 {'LAT': {'ATE': 'Nacional'}, 'LDS': {'DSA': [O... en una unica columna, también he intentado con bucle sobre root, he intentado con getchildren()....pero sin exito. Gracias

Comment: xmlDict = xmltodict.parse(xml_data)  # Parse XML

cols = xmlDict['DS'].keys()
data = []

for i in xmlDict['DS']:
    child = xmlDict['DS'][i]
    data.append([child[subchild] for subchild in child])

df = pd.DataFrame(data).T  # Create DataFrame and transpose it.
df.columns = cols
print(df) ME ARROJA                                                                                                
         LAT                                                                       LDS
0 Nacional [{'NIF': None, 'APE': None, 'RC': '8132404VL10...

Comment: Pero qué etiquetas exactamente quieres extraer? Y qué quieres hacer con la estructura jerárquica del XML? Quiero decir, muchas de las estiquetas están "unas dentro de otras" ¿cómo querrías eso en el dataframe?

Comment: @abufalia cada etiqueta distinta una columna, he intentado haciendo con find y el nombre de la etiqueta pero claro al haber vacias me arroja el error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Estoy intentando algo sencillo, sacar el texto de la etiqueta RC a una columna de pandas, con idea de añadir a posteriori las etiquetas que sean interesantes, o que tengan texto.... for nodo in raiz.iter('RC'):
    print(RC.text) y Me arroja el siguente error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'                       @abufalia

Comment: con XMLTODICT                                                                                                             doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())
RC = []
DEL=[]
MUN=[]
columnas=['RC','DEL','MUN']

for a in doc['DS']['LDS']['DSA']:
    RC.append(a['RC'])
for b in doc['DS']['LDS']['DSA']['LBI']['BIE']['IBI']:
    DEL.append(b['DEL'])
    MUN.append(b['MUN'])                                                                                                 Arroja el error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 0):

Buenas finalmente he obtenido el resultado que buscaba, con un proceso tedioso pero ha dado el resultado aunque seguro hay alguna manera de hacer esto para xml complejos mas efectivas, dejo el código(No esta depurado, ni nada) por si alguien le sirve de ayuda en  github.com/cafepoetica/Xml Los pasos han sido:

1.- Pasar a Diccionario con xmltodict.parse

2.- Pasar el Diccionario a DataFrame

3.- Seleccionar las filas y pasarlas con to_dict() a diccionario, seleccionando cada 'hilo' y quedandome con las columnas que me interesan, e ir desenrredando columna a columna(tras ir transponiendo), haciendo el mismo proceso diccionario a diccionario.

4.- Crear df_f con las columnas que me voy quedando para una union final en un unico dataframe

Dejo aqui un trozo de código:

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(doc)
df2=df.iloc[1].to_dict()
df3=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df2)
df4=df3.iloc[0].to_dict()
df5=pd.DataFrame(df4).T
df6=df5.iloc[0].to_dict()
df7=pd.DataFrame(df6).T
df7.head() #Me quedo con las columnas de nif a mun
df1f=df7[['NIF','RC','PROV',,'POL','PAR','ERR']]
df8=df7['LBI'].to_dict()
df9=pd.DataFrame(df8).T
df9.head()
df10=df9['BIE'].to_dict()
df11=pd.DataFrame({ key:pd.Series(value) for key, value in df10.items() }).T
df12=df11.to_dict()
df13=pd.DataFrame(df12)
df13.head() #Me quedo con dtr
df2f=df13[['DTR']]
df14=df13['DT'].to_dict()
df15=pd.DataFrame(df14).T
df15.head() #Me quedo con cmc,np,nm
df3f=df15[['CMC','NP','NM']]
```